# Google analytics anonymizeIp - how anonymous?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I know that the anonymizeIp-option causes google to strip the last octet from the users IP.

My question is, how much accuracy is left. Can I still see what country the visitor is coming from, what city?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any GeoIP databases should still work to detect at the country level, as the country would be determined by the first 3 octets.  The city-level detection will probably not work though.

Comment: Ok, cool. Do you have any references on that so I can read up on how it works?

Comment: @RikardUppström This should be a good starting point for learning about how IP allocations are handled.  http://www.iana.org/numbers/